# how to count specific numbers in the segment of the column in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to count how many times I see the number on the segments `0<x<10, 10<x<20, 20<x<30 and so on.`
I appreciate any advise.
Thank you!

```py
for segment in range(segments):
    seg = train.iloc[segment*rows:segment*rows+rows]
    x = seg['days']
    X_train.loc[segment, '0<x<10'] = x.between(0,10).count()
    X_train.loc[segment, '10<x<20'] = x.between(10,20).count()
    X_train.loc[segment, '20<x<30'] = x.between(20,30).count()
    X_train.loc[segment, '30<x<40'] = x.between(30,40).count()
    X_train.loc[segment, '40<x<50'] = x.between(40,50).count()
    X_train.loc[segment, '50<x<60'] = x.between(50,60).count()
    X_train.loc[segment, '60<x<70'] = x.between(60,70).count()
    X_train.loc[segment, '70<x<80'] = x.between(70,80).count()
    X_train.loc[segment, '80<x<90'] = x.between(80,90).count()
    X_train.loc[segment, '90<x<100'] = x.between(90,100).count()
```

I'm expecting to see the table X_train like this:

```
0<x<10   10<x<20  20<x<30 ...
600       114       76    ...
845       112       0     ...
```

But I got table which shows total numbers of lines in seg['days']:

```
0<x<10   10<x<20  20<x<30 ...
15000     15000    15000  ...
15000     15000    15000  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the `pandas` library; if not, it would be an excellent tool for your problem.

It sounds like you want to partition your data into groups and then count the number of values in each group between 0 and 100. A convenient way to do this with `pandas` is a [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) along with [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['x'], np.arange(0, 100, 10))).count()
```

Comment: It looks like a good idea, but I have 100 data sets with 100 rows with column 'days', and I need to calculate frequency for each segment of days for each data set and create a new data set:
                                     0<x<10      10<x<20      20<x<30 ...
freq. for 1st data set        600              114             76    ...
freq. for 2nd data set       845              112              0     ...

I do not know how to make this code work in my loop.

Comment: I just found the way: since operation x.between(0,10) gives you Boolean result (True or False), in order to calculate all True results you just need to use Sum function instead of count(). So using lines:
X_train.loc[segment, '10<x<20'] = sum(x.between(10, 20))
X_train.loc[segment, '20<x<30'] = sum(x.between(20, 30))
X_train.loc[segment, '30<x<40'] = sum(x.between(30, 40)) and so on...
I got the result I wanted. Any way thank you for your help, you are the only one who replied!

Comment: No problem. Glad you found your answer!